# How do I get a child of a QDialog (access a button) with an enum?

Tags: qt, enums, qt5, qt5.12

I've got a button, assigned to a **QDialog** this way:

```
QPushButton *button = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::StandardButton::Ok);
```

**How do I get it as a child from a QDialog?**

I wanted to use:

```
parentWidget->findChild<QPushButton*>(QDialogButtonBox::StandardButton::Ok);
```

but `findChild<T>` needs a QString.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need that? If you already have a specialized function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do... this looks to me like an x->y problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the buttonBox by its object name first, and then you can get the button you want:

```
QDialogButtonBox* buttonBox = dialog.findChild<QDialogButtonBox*>("buttonBox");
if (buttonBox)
{
    QPushButton* btn = buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
    if (btn)
    {
        qDebug() << "Find it!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`findChild`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) finds a Qt Object by objectname.
You have to give your button an Object name first using:

`setObjectName(const QString &name)`

See documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop).